# What is the significance of the last 5 digits of Base 58 WIF?

Tags: wallet, base58, wallet-import-format

I'm trying to understand the Base 58 WIF number. While messing around with importing on blockchain I noticed that if you change the last five (or so) digits, it doesn't appear to affect which address is imported - 
i.e. i get the "This address is already present in the wallet" note.
Does anyone have any insight they could share about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last 4 bytes of the WIF format is a checksum. The details can be seen here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format

That's approximately 5 characters of Base58 that are essentially redundant. This is so that errors in the WIF encoded private key can be detected easily. I believe some wallets will simply ignore the checksum if it's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

A picture is worth a 1000 words. See `Figure 6` from [Chapter 4](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/first_edition/ch04.asciidoc) of the **Bitcoin Book**. The last 4 bytes are used as a *checksum* for error checking. The *version* prefix is different for Bitcoin altcoin forks. See the 3rd column of this [Table](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table) for versions used by various altcoins.